# Blender not starting Lubuntu 13.04 PowerPC

Tags: software-installation, apt, vnc, macintosh, opengl

I have installed Blender via `apt-get` on a PowerPC G4 Mac Mini running Lubuntu 13.04, and now it will not start over **VNC**.

Output from running `blender` in the terminal:

```
Color management: using fallback mode for management
Xlib:  extension "XInputExtension" missing on display "lubuntu:1".
connect failed: No such file or directory
/build/buildd/blender-2.66a/intern/ghost/intern/GHOST_WindowX11.cpp:192: X11 glXQueryVersion() failed, verify working openGL system!
initial window could not find the GLX extension, exit!
```

I know GLX is part of OpenGL, but I have no knowledge of how to install it.

Comment: `glxgears` is a common OGL test program.  Try installing that (`apt-cache search glxgears` should lead you somewhere) and run it from the command line.  Hopefully it is just some pieces of X that were missed by the blender dependences.

Comment: I've done some Googling, and I see all kinds of problem reports with the Radeon 9200 drivers on Lubuntu.  Did you have to force it to use the Vesa drivers to make graphics work? If so, you can't expect anything but decent 2D performance with those drivers. Blender requires solid hardware 3D support. This is true even though the final 3D renderer is pure software. You still need hardware 3D support to get real-time model manipulation while building and animating your scene.

Comment: @goldilocks I have installed glxgears, and it fails with the error: `Error: Couldn't get an RGB, Double-buffered visual`

Comment: @WarrenYoung I am using the machine over ssh and VNC on my local network so I don't know about the drivers

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualGL and http://serverfault.com/questions/174003/how-can-opengl-graphics-be-displayed-remotely-using-vnc

Answer (score 0):

I use this on my lubuntu

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:irie/blender
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install blender
```

[This](http://cahyoonsby.blogspot.com/2015/01/menginstall-blender-software-animasi-3d.html) is my screenshot when I install blender on lubuntu.